# How do I hide the black screen of the console application?

Tags: c#, console-application

How do I hide the black screen of the console application?

googled it, found nothing...

Comment: You mean you want a console application without the console?

Comment: See: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/ea8b0fd5-a660-46f9-9dcb-d525cc22dcbd

Comment: Every time I see this (and trust me, it's regrettably often), it never fails to strike me as absolutely the *strangest* request. Why create a console application in the first place if you don't want a console window? Something is seriously broken there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Project - Properties - Output type. Change it from Console Application to Windows Application.